# RichTextBox takes too long to print results

Tags: c#, winforms, richtextbox

In `WinForms`, I have a list with more than 10000 rows.
I have to print each row in a `RichTextBox` control, but the program freezes, and takes something like 10 minutes. In order to create the list, the program takes 3 seconds.

My problem is: how can I print the result without waiting so much?

Here's the code:

```
for(int i=0; i < 1000; i++) {
  //(...) add a row
}

foreach (string item in list)
{
    richTextBox1.Text += item + "\r\n";
}
```

Comment: You should use StringBuilder to create the full string from the list and then assign that to `richTextBox1.Text`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`StringBuilder`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder(v=vs.110).aspx) and assign its result to the `richTextBox1.Text`:

```
  var sb = new StringBuilder();
  foreach (string item in list)
  {
     sb.Append(item + "\r\n");
  }
  richTextBox1.Text += sb.ToString();
```